# SqlDataAdapter taking too long to Fill VB.NET SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, dataadapter

I'm working on a winform application and I'm using a table named *[File]* in my SQL Server database.

I have a form that views some of "[File]" fields **fID and fName** in a combobox named ***SearchName***. *fID for Value and fName for Display.*
SearchName Combobox is bound to dataset with dataadapter filling table with fID, fName, fPhoneNumber, fBalance, so I can use fName and fID.

I have also textboxes to add new "File" data like : fName, fAge, fNationality,fSex with a Save button with another combobox showing something called **"Source"**.

When User clicks **Save** the data is saved to table [File] In DB and the adapter is filled again.

The dataset tableadapter was using a stored procedure as the following:

```
create proc [dbo].[ReadFileData](@fid int,@filter varchar(20))
as
begin
declare @f varchar(20)=@filter;
declare @id int =@fid;
if(@id=-1)
begin
if(@f='All')
select fID,fName,fPhoneNumbers,fBalance from [File]      
else
if(@f='Blocked')
select fID,fName,fNotes,fBalance,fBlockDate,uFullName 
from [File],[User] where fBlocked='True' and fBlocker=[uID]
order by fBlockDate desc
else
if(@f='nonBlocked')
select fID,fName,fPhoneNumbers,fBalance from [File] where fBlocked='False'
else
if(@f='notReady')
select fID,fName,fPhoneNumbers,fBalance from [File] where fAllTestsOK='False' and fBlocked='False'
else
if(@f='Ready')
select fID,fName,fPhoneNumbers,fBalance from [File] where fAllTestsOK='True' and fBlocked='False'
else
if(@f='NegBalanced')
select fID,fName,fPhoneNumbers,fBalance from [File] where fBalance<0
end
else
select f.fID,fName,fSex,fBirthDate,fPhoneNumbers,fAddress,fNationality,fNotes,fBalance,fBlocked,(select uFullName from [User] where uid=f.fBlocker) as fBlocker,
fLastEdited,(select uFullName from [User] where [uID]=f.fEditor) as fEditor, fBlockDate from [File] f where fID=@fid
end
```

It was taking too much time to save and fill the combobox again. I searched over the internet and I found out the problem is called **"Patamter Sniffing/spoofing"**, because my procedure was selecting fields based on the values of the parameter it receives. I tried different ways to solve it, but nothing worked out for me. (P.S. I am using the same SP on other forms and data is filled immediately with no problems).

I deleted the whole dataset and created a new one with a new dataadapter using new Stored Procedure, this:

```
create proc [dbo].[GetAllFiles]
as
begin
select fID,fName,fPhoneNumbers,fBalance from [File]
end
```

Now first time the save and fill is done in no time, but after that it takes like 10+ seconds to fill.

I want to know what can I do to continue using the dataadapter to fill the combobox and solve time consuming problem? 
If you have any suspicions that might cause these kind of problems, please let me know.
What other code parts or even design pictures can I provide to make my problem clearer?

[image]

Comment: Instead of running the query again for a filter, you could use a DataView to apply a filter to the data you already have loaded.

Comment: Thank for the reply, but I have an entire project running with the same way. I use this a lot in this and other projects. I would like to know what is wrong with it and what takes the adapter so long?

Comment: I also would like to use the adapter so I can also use it for another combobox that views the fID.

Comment: If you fill a datatable with all rows, you can use a filter to display only some of them here and there.  You do not have to run a new query and create a new result set for a filter or find.

Comment: I am trying to view all rows as you can see in the last stored procedure. I want to refill it, because when user clicks "Save" there is a new row added or an existing row is edited in db. I'm trtying to keep Combobox list of names Up To Date after saving.

Comment: You should spend a few hours on MSDN.  You do not need to requery/refill/rebuild a datatable when you add rows; they can be refreshed.

Comment: Thanks A LOT! I  Used Update()  instead of Fill() and It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Plutonix. *He wrote it in a reply, just to make it clearer.*

*"You should spend a few hours on MSDN. You do not need to requery/refill/rebuild a datatable when you add rows; they can be refreshed. – Plutonix"*

I used DataAdapterName.Adapter.Update(DatasetName) in save button and other update places. And kept fill only in page load event.